# Chrome Extension - popup window, remove shadowed outline

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

So I've been recently trying to add an dark mode to my popup when I noticed this strange outline on the right and bottom side:

[image]

The outline has a white colored and a transparent part. It can't be removed with margin or padding and it seems like the outline doesn't even belong to the document body (does not get marked by developer tools).

Maybe it is caused by Windows (using Windows 10). But after removing window shadows by unchecking "*Advanced System Settings -> Settings Button -> Show Window Shadows*" nothing had happened.

It looks kinda bad, especially after adding more items. Maybe someone knows how to get rid of it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The shadow cannot be removed. The outline is a bug. Either in the browser or in your popup's html/css. P.S. Chrome doesn't respect most of accessibility options in Windows.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer wOxxOm :)