# How to round the corners of a popup that is a separate html file?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a chrome extension. When a user clicks on the extension, a popup gets opened. The popup is an html file. I have applied border and border-radius on the body element. But then the popup's corners can be seen coming out of the border. How to fix this issue? Image is attached for reference. I've highlighted the corners coming out of the border in red circles.
My code is as follows:

```
body {
  
  border: 2px solid #ff6100;
  
  border-radius: 0.5rem;

}
```

popup.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="sidebar">...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
   "manifest_version": 3,
   "name": "Sidebar Extension",
   "version": "1.0",
   "action": {
       "default_popup": "popup.html",
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please include a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: Instead of using `body` as a container use a different container if possible and you will not get this issue.

Comment: You can just add overflow:hidden to body, because it is not initally designed to keep things inside, it will strech as much as possible to show everything, unless otherwise stated in CSS. So, by adding `overflow:hidden` you make sure that `body` keeps everything within boundaries.

Comment: What sort of popup is this? I assume that the square edges (and the grey border, and the drop-shadow) are all parts of the 'popup' container itself and have nothing to do with your popup.html. Its a grey-bordered, drop-shadowed box into which your html is rendered.

Comment: @Moob it is the entire popup.html that is getting rendered. The line default_popup: popup.html indicates that when the user clicks on the extension icon, the whole popup.html is rendered as a popup

Comment: So the grey border and drop-shadow IS part of your popup.html? I'm dubious. I suggest that you use Chrome's dev tools to inspect the page and see where the border and drop-shadow is coming from. My guess is that it is from the container which holds your popup.html.

Comment: You can't control Chrome's popup frame. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957551/chrome-extension-popup-window-remove-shadowed-outline and https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5276357/How-do-I-change-the-shape-of-popup-html-in-a-chrom and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899635/how-to-make-border-radius-in-popup-chrome-extension

Comment: @Moob you have a point. I tried inspecting from where this grey border and box-shadow is coming from. I inspected the top-most html element but there is no border or box-shadow on that element. I can't tell from where these two are coming from

Comment: Also there is no file other than popup.html in the whole project. i can't find the container , if any, that holds the popup.html file from the chrome dev tools

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding some CSS to reset the margin and padding for the  element in your popup.html file. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 2px solid #ff6100;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
      }
    /* Add other styles as needed */
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="sidebar">...</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

In css you can add overflow: hidden; to your body element so that it will not come out of the borders.
I hope it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am sorry that it's not working I'm gonna check that for you again; I hope I can find another solution.

Answer (score -1):

try background-color:transparent and give inner background if needed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).